# Why was Asuna late?

Tags: sword-art-online

In season 2, episode 20, Asuna is disconnected from ALO by her mother because she is late for dinner.  Apparently, this isn't the first time she was late, and her mother said so.

The world of SAO allows for an in-game AI-that's-classified-as-an-item/NPC (Yui)to make phone calls, or players to do their homework.  Clearly there are extensions, apps, and 3rd party code available to run in ALO, kind of like with WoW here in <s>The Matrix</s> reality.

Clocks and timers are usually very easy to program, and it wouldn't surprise me if something as sophisticated as a VRMMO already had a rudimentary alarm clock built in.

How/why did Asuna get blindsided by the time?  Is it just a plotpoint meant for the audience to relate to being so engrossed in the game that you lose track of the time?

Comment: isn't Yui's functionality as a Navigation Pixie in ALO different from your normal Navigation Pixie because she's an MHCP AI from SAO who had greater permissions and freedom (ie. she can leave the game as shown when Kirito tests out the cameras for her to use in Andrew's Bar). particularly i think any sorta reminder she give is more because she's self aware as opposed to being a predefined function of her programming

Comment: Part of that might be "well, it's because she's Yui", and part of it might be "because plot", but my point about the 3rd party code is the main point.  Heck, Yui should be able to work as an alarm clock!

Answer (score 1):

She totally could set an alarm. Back in the first episode of the series, Klein had an alarm set up so he remembered to logout when his pizza arrived.

IMO, she didn't simply overstay because she was enjoying it so much, her strained relationship with her family made her to WANT to be late on purpose, so she didn't bother to set up an alarm or tell Yui to remind her about dinner, but alas, we can only speculate about it since it wasn't revealed what were Asuna's actual thoughts on that specific matter.